# Angular cannot loop a list of ElementRef

Tags: html, angular, typescript, elementref

I have a list of ElementRef for all my inputs but when I try to add listeners to them it makes like `textInputs` is empty but it's not.

```
@ViewChildren('text_input') textInputs!: QueryList<ElementRef>;

ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.initTextInputsListeners();
}

private initTextInputsListeners() {
    this.textInputs.forEach(input => {
      const inputElement = input.nativeElement;
      const parentNode = inputElement.parentNode;
      inputElement.addEventListener('focus', () => {
        parentNode.classList.add('user-input-active')
      });
      inputElement.addEventListener('focusout', () => {
        if (inputElement.value === '') parentNode.classList.remove('user-input-active');
      });
    });
  }
```

```html
<div class="user-input send-message" [formGroup]="userInputForm" (ngSubmit)="onSendMessage()">
      <div class="user-input-box">
        <label for="message">Send message</label>
        <input id="message" class="form-control" type="text" name="message" #text_input formControlName="message" (keyup.enter)="onSendMessage()">
        <button class="submit-btn" type="submit" value="" (click)="onSendMessage()">
          <svg width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path
              d="m3.4 20.4l17.45-7.48a1 1 0 0 0 0-1.84L3.4 3.6a.993.993 0 0 0-1.39.91L2 9.12c0 .5.37.93.87.99L17 12L2.87 13.88c-.5.07-.87.5-.87 1l.01 4.61c0 .71.73 1.2 1.39.91z"/>
          </svg>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: First, why would you even do this with JS like this? You can use angular for this, like you do for `(ngSubmit), (click)...` event. There is also one for focus. Second point: Why use JS at all for this, you can use [:focus-within](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within) to achieve this with CSS alone.

Comment: Because i need to check if there is text inside

Comment: This doesn't answer the question why you do this the non-angular way without using `focus` event handler?

Comment: I just forgot that happends

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your code looks like work. So the problem is that when you execute the `initTextInputsListeners` textInputs have not all the inputs

So To be sure, you can subscribe to `this.textInputs.changes`

```
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.textInputs.changes.pipe(startWith(null)).subscribe((_) => {
      this.initTextInputsListeners();
    });
  }
```

There're another approach to achieve you want that it's use directives

You can use a directive applied to your inputs like

```
@Directive({
  selector: '[specialfocus]'
})
export class AddClassParentDirective {
  @Input('specialfocus') class="user-input-active"
  @HostListener('focus') addClass(){
    this.el.nativeElement.parentNode.classList.add(this.class)
  }
  @HostListener('blur') removeClass(){
    this.el.nativeElement.parentNode.classList.remove(this.class)
  }
  constructor(private el:ElementRef) { }
}
```

And use as

```
<div class="user-input-box">
  <label for="message">Send message</label>
  <input [specialfocus] class="form-control" type="text" />
</div>
```

Or use a directive applied to the div (see that in this case I use as selector `'.user-input-box2'`, so each div that has a class "user-input-box2" is really a UserInputBoxDirective

```
@Directive({
  selector: '.user-input-box2'
})
export class UserInputBoxDirective implements AfterViewInit,OnDestroy {
  focus:boolean=false;
  subscription:any=null
  @HostBinding('class.user-input-active') get _(){
    return this.focus?true:null
  }
  @ContentChild(HTMLInputElement) input:HTMLInputElement
  constructor(private el:ElementRef) { }
  ngAfterViewInit()
  {
    const inputs=this.el.nativeElement.getElementsByTagName('input')
    if (inputs && inputs.length)
    this.subscription=merge(fromEvent(inputs[0],'focus').pipe(map(_=>true)),
                            fromEvent(inputs[0],'blur').pipe(map(_=>false)))
                            .subscribe(res=>{
                              this.focus=res
                            })
  }
  ngOnDestroy()
  {
    this.subscription && this.subscription.unsubscribe
  }
}
```

You use like

```
<div class="user-input-box2">
  <label for="message">Send message</label>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" />
</div>
```

You has the three approach (your's and this about directives) in this [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-xhqbjw?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 1):

Easiest solution would be to not use JS for this at all. This is standard CSS stuff that has fairly good support in modern browsers:

Use [focus-within](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:focus-within) to determine if there is a focus active in a container.

Second way to do this with CSS is to use the [:has() css pesude-class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:has), but this has poorer css support. If you only want to activate this rule if the input is selected, you can modify the HTML markup so the focus-within only triggers if the input is in focus.

In the example below I color the text pink and fill the SVG with blue if focus is inside the `.user-input-box` element

```css
.user-input-box:focus-within {
  color: pink
}

.user-input-box:focus-within svg {
  fill: blue
}
```

```html
<div class="user-input-box">
  <label for="message">Send message</label>
  <input id="message" class="form-control" type="text" name="message" #text_input formControlName="message">
  <button class="submit-btn" type="submit" value="">
          <svg width="32" height="32" viewBox="0 0 24 24">
            <path
              d="m3.4 20.4l17.45-7.48a1 1 0 0 0 0-1.84L3.4 3.6a.993.993 0 0 0-1.39.91L2 9.12c0 .5.37.93.87.99L17 12L2.87 13.88c-.5.07-.87.5-.87 1l.01 4.61c0 .71.73 1.2 1.39.91z"/>
          </svg>
        </button>
</div>
```

Comment: Sure! focus-within is with us sometime ago (Really I thought that was "new"), thanks for the review

Comment: No I need to check if there is text inside the input